# Netstat showing a strange process named "public"

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

I have a several process named "public" that listen for TCP connections.

Due to this extremely common name, I was not able to identify what is this process and what is its purpose.

[screenshot of netstat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeAvU.png)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1562/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1637/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1676/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42546         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16561/public    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1570/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38646         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20186/public    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44055         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7307/public     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36951         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1515/public     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17970/postgres  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1570/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45402         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7077/public     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1676/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35932         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18847/public    
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      7365/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::42                   :::*                    LISTEN      1562/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1676/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      1570/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2327/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      17970/postgres  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1570/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::8001                 :::*                    LISTEN      2319/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8002                 :::*                    LISTEN      2161/docker-proxy
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1570/named      
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                1570/named
```

Does anyone know what this process is?

Comment: What do you get if you do a `ps -fp 16561` (replacing the number with the PID of each of these processes in turn)?

Comment: This is what I get  
    aschen    1842     1  0 12:36 ?        00:00:00 Passenger RubyApp: /home/aschen/www/apollo/code/public

Now I know that this my Rails application running, the name is because the code is in the `public` folder..  

Thanks for the help, I didn't know this `ps` arguments :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've put my comment down as an answer so others can find it if they're looking.

Answer (score 4):

Run `ps -fp 16561` (replacing the number with the PID of each of the mystery processes in turn) to see what the application actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Use lsof to see what files are used by these processes and maybe you can get some hint about what it does

```
lsof -p 16561
```